# Unable to connect to SHT4x sensor probe through I2C bus

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

```
Error trying to execute serialNumber(): ReceK on transmit of address
Error trying to execute serialNumber(): Received NACK on transmit of address
Error trying to execute measureHighPrecision(): Received NACz��trnsmit of ad���Error trying to execute serialNumber(): Received NACK on transmit of address
Error trying to execute measureHighPrecision(): Received NACK on transmit of address
Error trying to execute measureHighPrecision(): Received NACK on transmit of address
```

This is the error I receive when I try to connect my probe to my Arduino Uno.

I have soldered jumper wires to my probe to use with my microcontroller. The humidity probe is an [SHT40](https://sensirion.com/media/documents/33FD6951/6555C40E/Sensirion_Datasheet_SHT4x.pdf) Sensirion probe. The code is the example usage code you find when you install the Sensirion SHT4x library.

```
 /*
 * Copyright (c) 2021, Sensirion AG
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *
 * * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
 *   list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 * * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
 *   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
 *   and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 * * Neither the name of Sensirion AG nor the names of its
 *   contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
 *   this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
 * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
 * ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
 * LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
 * CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
 * SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
 * INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
 * CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
 * ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SensirionI2CSht4x.h>
#include <Wire.h>

SensirionI2CSht4x sht4x;

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(115200);
    while (!Serial) {
        delay(100);
    }

    Wire.begin();

    uint16_t error;
    char errorMessage[256];

    sht4x.begin(Wire);

    uint32_t serialNumber;
    error = sht4x.serialNumber(serialNumber);
    if (error) {
        Serial.print("Error trying to execute serialNumber(): ");
        errorToString(error, errorMessage, 256);
        Serial.println(errorMessage);
    } else {
        Serial.print("Serial Number: ");
        Serial.println(serialNumber);
    }
}

void loop() {
    uint16_t error;
    char errorMessage[256];

    delay(1000);

    float temperature;
    float humidity;
    error = sht4x.measureHighPrecision(temperature, humidity);
    if (error) {
        Serial.print("Error trying to execute measureHighPrecision(): ");
        errorToString(error, errorMessage, 256);
        Serial.println(errorMessage);
    } else {
        Serial.print("Temperature:");
        Serial.print(temperature);
        Serial.print("\t");
        Serial.print("Humidity:");
        Serial.println(humidity);
    }
}
```

[image: soldering]

[image: Image of sensor]

[image: connections based on github image]

The soldered wires move a bit, but they are all still in contact and strongly intact.

Comment: Have you tried the [I2C Scanner sketch](https://learn.adafruit.com/scanning-i2c-addresses/arduino)? That can show, if there is at least a device found on the bus (and its address)

Comment: Do you have the requisite pull-up resistors for your I2C bus?  The Arduinos internal pull-ups aren't strong enough.